# `next-sitemap` duplicated language in alternate ref path (href)

Tags: next.js, sitemap.xml

..I have a Next.js application with multi-language support (English as the default language and German as the secondary one - English is on https://mywebsite.com and German on https://mywebsite.com/de).

I'm using `next-sitemap` to generate a sitemap for the page using alternate refs to link the English and German versions of the pages. The following is my next-sitemap config:

```js
/** @type {import('next-sitemap').IConfig} */
module.exports = {
  siteUrl: `https://mywebsite.com`,
  generateRobotsTxt: true,
  exclude: ['/app/*', '/social-redirect'],
  robotsTxtOptions: {
    policies: [
      {
        userAgent: '*',
        [process.env.VERCEL_ENV !== 'preview' && process.env.VERCEL_ENV !== 'development'
          ? 'allow'
          : 'disallow']: '/',
      },
    ],
  },
  alternateRefs: [
    {
      href: 'https://mywebsite.com',
      hreflang: 'en',
    },
    {
      href: 'https://mywebsite.com/de',
      hreflang: 'de',
    },
  ],
};
```

In the generated sitemap the English entries of the sitemap look good. They have the correct alternate refs. But in the German entries of the sitemap, the alternate refs have the language in the path twice, so for example: `https://mywebsite.com/de/de/blog`. Is this an issue of `next-sitemap` or am I doing something wrong? I would be glad if someone could help me with that!

Comment: Try removing the `/de` from the alternate ref's `href`.

Comment: Hi @juliomalves,
thanks for your comment - I tried that already. The result is that in the English entries of the sitemap the alternate refs to German are not correct - they just also point to the English version.

Answer (score 0):

This is also happening to me. I think it is an issue of next-sitemap

In my case I have languages **en** and **en-gb** The urls generated are:

- `<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://localhost:3000/en/en-gb/blog/"/>`
- `<xhtml:link  rel="alternate" hreflang="en-gb" href="http://localhost:3000/en-gb/en-gb/blog/"/>`

You can use transform prop of **next-sitemap.config.js** to configure a replacement

```
`transform: async (config, path) => {
         return { ...config,
                 loc: path.replace('/en-gb/en-gb', '/en-gb')
                } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue and a workaround can be found on: https://github.com/iamvishnusankar/next-sitemap/issues/172

The solution looks like this (irrelevant config has been removed):

```js
/** @type {import('next-sitemap').IConfig} */
module.exports = {
  siteUrl: `https://mywebsite.com`,
  alternateRefs: [
    {
      href: 'https://mywebsite.com',
      hreflang: 'en',
    },
    {
      href: 'https://mywebsite.com/de',
      hreflang: 'de',
    },
  ],
  // This is the workaround
  transform: (config, path) => {
    // The first few fields are given their default values as seen on:
    // https://github.com/iamvishnusankar/next-sitemap#custom-transformation-function
    return {
      loc: path,
      changefreq: config.changefreq,
      priority: config.priority,
      lastmod: config.autoLastmod ? new Date().toISOString() : undefined,

      // This is where the alternate urls are fixed
      alternateRefs: config.alternateRefs.map((alternate) => {
        // No need to change the path for the default locale
        if (!hasLocaleInPath(path)) {
          return alternate
        }

        return {
          ...alternate,
          // Note: The alternate.href already includes the locale so removing
          // the locale from the path to avoid dual locales.
          href: alternate.href + '/' + path.substring(4),
          hrefIsAbsolute: true,
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

function hasLocaleInPath(path) {
  // Needs to change to support more locales
  return path.substring(1, 3) === 'de'
}
```